# How to get the latest release version in Github only use python-requests?

Tags: python, html, git, github, python-requests

Recently,I make an app and upload it to my GitHub release page.I want to make a function to check update to get the latest version(in the release pages).

I try to use `requests` module to crawl my release page to get the latest version.Here it a minimal example of my code:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

response = requests.get("https://github.com/v2ray/v2ray-core/releases")
html = etree.HTML(response.text)
Version = html.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a")
print(Version)
```

I think the xpath is right,because I use `chrome -> copy -> copy xpath`.But it return me a `[]`.it can't find the latest version.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A direct way is to use [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#get-the-latest-release), it is easy to do and don't need xpath.

---

The URL should be:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/latest
```

So if you want to get the latest release version of the repository. Here is an easy example only using the `requests` module:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/v2ray/v2ray-core/releases/latest")
print(response.json()["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the github url, you can only use the requests.get, when it returns the code 200, the url change to the latest version.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/releases/latest")
actual_version = response.url.split('/').pop()
```

For example, I'll put here with an personal app:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://github.com/Lokost/Loko_qr/releases/latest")
version = response.url.split("/").pop() # This will return "v0.2.0" in the day of this post.
```